# centos 7 troubles with apache

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since lun 2017-06-05 10:27:06 PDT; 47s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 37620 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 37609 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 37609 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jun 05 10:27:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain httpd[37609]: httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on ...ection
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain kill[37620]: kill: cannot find process ""
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Can you share the line 353 of your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file in order to see what the syntax error is? Do `sed -n 353p /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your Apache configuration; there appears to be an error, as the log you have shown tells us:

```
jun 05 10:27:06 localhost.localdomain httpd[37609]: httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on ...ection
```

Comment: Always helpful to run `apachectl -t` after making changes to Apache configuration files.